laravel factory with multiple foreignid
This is my order migration :

this is my order factory :

and this is my database seeder :

the migration seed is run smoothly but i end up with 350 employee where i just need 50 employee.
notice in my order factory...what i want to acheve is :

i want "awakIntat" column is take from an employee.
i want "awakCok" column is take from employee.
i want "kasir" column is take from employee.
and all the employee is not same person.

how should i generate the seeder data correctly???...sorry for the local language XD

Don't post images of code, put the code in a code block in the question. If someone wants to answer your question, they will want to be able to copy your code and make some changes to it.
